# Remove row in a datatable using listview itemdeleting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to delete a row in the data table when the user clicked the button with the item deleting event. Am I missing something? When i click the Linkbutton `lnkdelete`, the row is still there

aspx code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Product ID</th>
                                                        <th>Product Name</th>
                                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                    </tr>    
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <asp:ListView ID="lvSODetails" runat="server" 
                                                        onitemdeleting="lvSODetails_ItemDeleting" >
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td><asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' /></td>
                                                                <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
                                                                <td><%# Eval("Quantity") %></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" 
                                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" CommandName="Remove" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td colspan="4"><h5><center>Select a product first then click "Add Product".</center></h5></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                    </asp:ListView>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

c#

```
void GetSODetails()
    {
        lvSODetails.DataSource = SODetails;
        lvSODetails.DataBind();
    }

protected void lvSODetails_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        SODetails = (DataTable)Session["sodetails"];
        string lblID = (lvSODetails.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblID") as Label).Text;
        DataRow[] drr = SODetails.Select("ProductID=' " + lblID + " ' ");
        foreach (var row in drr)
            row.Delete();
        SODetails.AcceptChanges();
        GetSODetails();
    }
```

Comment: The CommandName of your LinkButton should be "Delete" not "Remove". This will cause the ItemDeleting event to be raised. At the moment I don't think it will be being called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong property on your `LinkButton` for your situation.

Remove all the command-related stuff and just subscribe to the event you already have.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete"
                runat="server"
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
                OnItemDeleting="lvSODetails_ItemDeleting" />
```